# Amazon Lex - slot type synonym values are not recognized

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have created custom slot as to receive the values as yes or no. I have created synonyms for yes as yep, y, yah. But this is not properly recognized during lex bot input. Am i doing wrong?. Please help.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have saved the slot type after adding the synonyms, and then make double sure that the version of slot is pointed to LATEST in the Slots field in intent. Then Build the bot and you are good to go.
Refer below image where you have to select LATEST:

[image: slots]

I was facing same problem and thats how problem was solved.
Hope it helps.